# My program is outputting too many letter (bananaanaanaana when its meant to output banananana)

Tags: python

my task: write a program that reads three lines of input. The first line will be a word, then a number of characters to repeat, then a number of repeats.

my current program is:

```
word = input('Enter the word: ')
repeat = int(input('Enter the repeat length: '))
count = int(input('Enter the repeat count: '))
print(word + word[repeat+1:]*count)
```

but it outputs to many letter

if the word is 'banana'
it prints out: bananaanaanaana 
if repeat length is 2
and repeat count is 3

i have no idea why this is

Comment: Your task is not clear (to me) repeat which letters, count what ? can you provide an expected output ?

Comment: Try print(word + word[len(word)-repeat:]*count)

Comment: the expected output is in the question (banananana)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What seems to be happening is your code

```
word[repeat+1:]
```

is going to the 3 place of the string:
0: B
1: a
2: n
3: a
4: n
5: a

Then from that point, it concatenates 'Ana' to the end of the string the amount time it's told by count.

Some minor adjustments should give you the proper output knowing this information.

Answer (score 2):

Break your `print` in interpreter to understand what is happening, (for `word = 'banana'`, `repeat = 2` & `count = 3` )

```
>>> word = 'banana'
>>> word[2+1:]
'ana'
>>> word+'ana'*3
'bananaanaanaana'
```

Actually you are executing the following statement through `print`:

```
>>> 'banana'+'ana'+'ana'+'ana'
'bananaanaanaana'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your last line isn't quite doing what you think. Specifically, the bit `word[repeat+1:]` is a slice of `word` starting with the character at index `repeat + 1` and ending at the end of the string.

It seems like you want to extract the last `repeat` characters of `word`. To do that, you'd want to use `word[-repeat:]`. (You can read this as "the slice of `word` starting `repeat` characters from the end of the string and ending at the end of the string.")

With this in mind, everything should work as you'd like if you replace your last line with the following:
`print(word + word[-repeat:]*count)`